# Change sorter in category select box to <ul> <li>

Tags: magento2, category, ajax, category-products

> I want to change sort by select box into `<ul> <li>` type by using
>   javascript so I can change style css for it. 
>  How can i do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing. Hide the select box and add your custom `<ul> <li>` below select box.

Then add jQuery function on click of `<li>` to change the value of select box accordingly.